# Is CompositDisposable.add() / OpenHashSet.add() idempotent?

Tags: rx-java2, composite

I'm looking at `CompositeDisposable` docs and it says that `.dispose()` is idempotent. Is `.add()` also idempotent?

```
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = ...
Disposable disposable = ...

compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
```

How many Disposables is compositeDisposable tracking? I see that its backed by an `OpenHashSet` but it's not very clear how `OpenHashSet.add()` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is copied from [`Disposable.dispose()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/Disposable.html#dispose--) and a suggestion to the developer implementing it. And of course they made `CompositeDisposable.dispose()` idempotent as well.

For `CompositeDisposable.add(Disposable)` you already noticed that it's backed by an `OpenHashSet`. As this is a `Set` "implementation", it ensures that elements are only added once, thus `add()` is idempotent for both classes.